# Using jQuery, how can I clone forms elements and increment the name and id of the cloned elements?

Tags: jquery, clone, increment

I know there are a lot of questions on Stack about this topic, but I cannot get my specific problem to work. I've looked at this question: [jquery increment id and name of children within appended rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917984/jquery-increment-id-and-name-of-children-within-appended-rows)

And used the code provided there, but I can't get my example to work. I have a fiddle up here: https://jsfiddle.net/af3z0kx5/2/

using the following HTML:

```
<main>
<form class="application">
<h3>Work Experience</h3>
<p class="note">Note: We check all references. Click the (+) or (-) buttons below to add or remove previous employment records.</p>
      <div class="work-experience">
        <div class="section group full">
          <div class="col span_6_of_12">
            <label for="fromdate">From (start date)</label>
            <input type="date" id="fromdate" name="From-Date" />
          </div>
          <div class="col span_6_of_12">
            <label for="todate">To (start date)</label>
            <input type="date" id="todate" name="To-Date" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <label for="workexp-employer">Employer's Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="Work-Exp-Employer" id="workexp-employer" />

        <label for="workexp-employer-address">Employer's Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="Work-Exp-Employer-Address" id="workexp-employer-address" placeholder="Street Address, State, and ZIP"/>

        <label for="workexp-employers-phone">Employer's Phone</label>
        <input type="tel" name="Work-Exp-Employer-Phone" id="workexp-employers-phone" pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}" placeholder="ex. 123-456-7890" />

        <label for="workexp-duties">Your Duties</label>
        <textarea placeholder="Summarize" class="duties"></textarea>

        <label for="workexp-supervisor">Supervisor's Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="Work-Exp-Supervisor" id="workexp-supervisor" />

        <div class="section group full">
          <div class="col span_6_of_12">
            <label for="starting-salary">Starting Rate/Salary</label>
            <input type="text" id="starting-salary" name="Starting-Salary" />
          </div>
          <div class="col span_6_of_12">
            <label for="ending-salary">Ending Rate/Salary</label>
            <input type="text" id="ending-salary" name="Ending-Salary" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <label for="workexp-leaving">Specific Reason for Leaving</label>
        <input type="text" name="Work-Exp-Leaving" id="workexp-leaving" />
        <hr />
      </div>
      <div class="control">
        <a href="#" class="add-work-exp">&nbsp;</a>
        <a href="#" class="remove-work-exp">&nbsp;</a>
      </div>
</form>
</main>
```

And the jQuery:

```
var i = $(".application .work-experience").length;
$(".add-work-exp").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var clonedRow = $(".work-experience").clone().find("input:text, textarea").val("").end();
    i++;
    $("*[name*='1']", clonedRow).attr('id', function() {
        var attrval = $(this).attr("id");
        attrval = attrval.replace(/\d/g, "");
        while($('#' + attrval + i).size() > 0) {
            i++;
        }
        return attrval + i;
    }).attr('name', function() {
        var attrval = $(this).attr("name");
        attrval = attrval.replace(/\d/g, "");
        return attrval + i;
    });
    $(".work-experience").append(clonedRow);
});

$(".remove-work-exp").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 $("form .work-experience").last().remove();
});
```

The issues I am having with this code:

1. The cloning puts the cloned code inside of the `.work-experience` div. I need it to go below it and outside of it. (I tried using `.insertAfter` instead of `.append` and that made the whole div disappear for some reason.)
2. The actual names and id attributes of each input do not get a number added to them. I need a -1, -2, -3 etc. added to the name and id of each input in the cloned div.

Thank you for any help you can give. I am not that good at jQuery (obviously) but I need to get this solved.

Comment: #1) http://api.jquery.com/after/  `$('.work-experience').after('new html')`

Comment: #2) None of your name attributes have a `1` in them.  The finder shouldn't be matching anything

Comment: Side note; `$("*[name*='1']", clonedRow)` should really be `clonedRow.find("[name*='1']"` as clonedRow is a jQuery object.  Both will work, but the first is slightly misleading.

Comment: Sode note; do not do `$(this).attr("id");`  If you already have an element, to get an attribute (or a property in this case), just use `this.id`.  You do not need jQuery to access a property

Comment: @Taplar Thanks for the tips. When I change `.append` to `.after` it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Taplar I changed the code in the fiddle, but now it doesn't work at all. https://jsfiddle.net/7cup58y4/

Comment: `F12` to open your developer tools, go to the Console tab, try to add a new row.  Then try to find the `size()` method in the http://api.jquery.com/ for reference

Comment: @Taplar Thanks! Changed `size()` to `length` and it seems to be working now. Feel free to submit an answer and I'll mark it as accepted!

Comment: Since I gave you pointers towards your issue, and you solved it yourself, I would encourage you to summarize how you fixed your issue and make an answer yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big thank you to @Taplar for pointing me in the right direction.

I had 2 issues with my code:

1. I didn't have "_Name1" in my name or id attributes. The jQuery was looking for that and couldn't find it which is why it was not incrementing.
2. I was using a deprecated method - `size()` - this was causing an error. I changed it to `length` and it worked!

New fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/32r8z6xs/